# Multiple Highcharts based charts using ember.js

Tags: ember.js

My requirement is as follows:

I will be intially fetching my list of reports which will contain only the report Id.Based on the report Id, I need to fetch the data for each report .I have partially succeeded in achieving this requirement. Please find the link below:

```
http://jsbin.com/ditazibowe/1/edit
```

Now I need to somehow pass the reportId from my template to my model , so that it fetches the data for each report based on the id. Is this possible to achieve? Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please describe how you want to send the id? through an action eg clicking the chart ?

Comment: @melc . I want to pass the id from my template to the model. Initially a list of reports are fetched based on which I will render the chart component template for each chart.Now chart uses a model to fetch data.I need to some how pass the id to the chart during rendering. Right now I am not able to get it using .property("reportId") in the model. So what is the way to go about this?

Comment: did you try the proposed answer? is this what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the model a bit and replace all calls to jquery `$` with `this.$` in order to use the context of the specific context.

example,

http://jsbin.com/zawameqilo/1/edit?html,js,output

**js**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model:function()
    {
      var reportModel = [];
      reportData.forEach(function(reportDataItem){
        var reportDataObject = Ember.Object.create({});
        reportDataObject.reopen({
              reportId:reportDataItem.reportId,
              chartOptions:{chart:{
                       type: 'line',
              }},
              graphData:function(){
                return fetchData(this.get("reportId"));
              }.property("reportId")
           });
            reportModel.pushObject(reportDataObject);
          });
          return reportModel;
      }
        });
  ....

this.$('.chart').highcharts(chart);
```

....

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   {{#each model}}
   <h1>{{reportId}}</h1>
    {{chart- chartOptions=chartOptions reportId=reportId series=graphData}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```